# Bootstrap: pull left and right in panel footer breaks footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a a Bootstrap panel with two buttons in the footer:

```
    <div class="panel-footer">
        {{ Form::open( array('route' => array('dogs.edit', $dog->id), 'method' => 'get', "class" => 'col-lg-6 ')) }}
            {{ Form::submit("Edit", array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
        {{ Form::open( array('route' => array('dogs.destroy', $dog->id), 'method' => 'delete', "class" => 'col-lg-6 ')) }}
            {{ Form::submit("Delete", array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
```

The forms for each of the buttons have the class `pull-left` and `pull-right` so that they are each floated to either side of the panel footer.

The float is working, but the buttons are now outside of the footer:

[image]

I tried using the grid system instead of the pull helpers but I ended up with the same result.

I've also searched around for the solution (this has to be pretty common I would think) and haven't found an explanation that doesn't require overriding Bootstrap with custom css.

Is it possible to fix this with just Bootstrap or would I need to throw my own css in to fix it?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Just add a div with clearfix after the buttons

`<div class="clearfix"></div>`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I tried clearfix but in the wrong places.

Comment: To me seems hacky to have to do this.

Answer (score 71):

stalin's answer is correct, but you can use another approach that is more elegant

From Bootstrap Documentation ([#clearfix](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix))

> Easily clear floats by adding .clearfix to the parent element.

Just add clearfix to the parent div:

```
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
    {{ Form::open( array('route' => array('dogs.edit', $dog->id), 'method' => 'get', "class" => 'col-lg-6 ')) }}
        {{ Form::submit("Edit", array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    {{ Form::open( array('route' => array('dogs.destroy', $dog->id), 'method' => 'delete', "class" => 'col-lg-6 ')) }}
        {{ Form::submit("Delete", array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and clean ! Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

just add the class `text-right` on the panel-footer div

Answer (score 5):

I think its strange that .panel-footer isn't included in the clearfix css library already the way .panel-body and even .modal-footer are. Instead of having to remember to throw a clearfix class on ever footer (if you have a lot it can be a pain) its better to just add the clearfix css to .panel-footer in your master CSS or edit the library directly.

```
.panel-footer:before, .panel-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.panel-footer:after {
    clear: both;
}
```